# Unable to close tabs - they keep appearing again in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser, crash, browser-tabs

I have opened a dozen Firefox windows and I have about twenty tabs in every window.
I have set, that FF starts with tabs from last session (that is what I want).

Now, Firefox sometimes crashes (when running long - maybe after an hour or after a few hours).

But, in addition, Firefox crashes always, when I exit it.

So now, I would like to preserve some of tabs.

So, I close some other tabs, then I quit the FF - and it crashes in that moment. 
And when I start the FF again, it forget!, that I closed some tabs -> it means, that FF opens all tabs including those, what were not opened in time of closing the FF. (in other words, FF open not only the tabs, what existed in the moment of last closing FF, but also the tabs, what was closed some time before the moment of closing the FF)

Any advice?

Notice:
I run FF 47.0 on Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 32bit on Intel Core 2 Duo 4GB RAM.

Notice2 (or question2): 
There is very very DNS lookup requests from FF after it starts - it is ok?
These big amount of DNS request totaly slow down network for some minute(s) (I suppose, the Zyxel DSL modem is place, where congestion happen)

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.  You state it crashes sometimes then immediately state it crashes always!?!  Which is it? And the. After it crashes you close tabs? How?? It's also very broad. I'm sorry I don't see how we can help unless you clarify it!

Comment: Also, describe how you open so many instances of Firefox (is each using a different profile?).  How are you expecting Firefox to know what tabs to open next time if each instance has different tabs?

Comment: @fixer1234 No, one process, one profile. Many windows, in every window many tabs. Clear?

Comment: @dave OK, so when I work, after some time the FF crashes. Especially FF like to crash, when I open heavy pages like facebook. And besides this, it crashes now always, when I exit it. So I want to close some tabs and restart (I would like Firefox have only half of those tabs open, but there is no way to this target, because, when I click on every tab to see it and may be to close it, the FF crashes earlier, than I go through quarter of them. And if I close only a few and want restart FF, than FF crashes during shutting down and so it forget, that some tabs were closed and ceased to be open)

Comment: @dave After starting FF from crash, there is screen with options, where I can select, what tabs not load. So may be, I could beforehand walk through tabs, make some notices elsewhere about the content of every tab and then (after some small number of crashes), I could by unchecking on restore screen suppressed selected tabs... It will be work with this (and need to do it every time, I have many tabs open), but may be only solution???

Comment: Nobody knows, what to do with FF? It is not usable for normal working, as I described. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my dear, I tried something and:

1) switching off the hardware acceleration have not solved the problem

2) I am very curious, that here nobody proposed it: the main problem was Firefox DNS prefetching. (I had no information, that FF do such a thing - but whenever I found information, that FF does, I immediatelly try switch it off and the problem was solved)
So thank me ;-)